# What is the difference between AF_NETLINK(NETLINK_ROUTE) and AF_ROUTE sockets in Linux?

Tags: linux, sockets, kernel

I tried understanding why two different protocol family exists to manipulate kernel routing table via sockets. Can anyone pls help understanding me whats the difference between two types of sockets ? It looks like both serves the same purpose - Manipulating the kernel routing table, yet what is the criteria on the basis of which the programmer would decide whether to use `AF_ROUTE` Or `AF_NETLINK (NETLINK_ROUTE)` sockets ?

Creation of Two sockets type :

**sockfd = socket(AF_ROUTE, SOCK_RAW, 0);**

**sockfd = socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_ROUTE);**

Answer (score 7):

> Relating to the BSD Routing Socket In BSD TCP/IP stack implementation,
>   there is a special socket called the routing socket. It has an address
>   family of AF_ROUTE, a protocol family of PF_ROUTE and a socket type of
>   SOCK_RAW. The routing socket in BSD is used by processes to add or
>   delete routes in the kernel routing table.
>
> In Linux, the equivalent function of the routing socket is provided by
>   the netlink socket protocol type NETLINK_ROUTE. Netlink socket
>   provides a functionality superset of BSD's routing socket.

You can read more in this [article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7356?page=0,0).

Answer (score -2):

There are two ways of communication between user space and kernel space. One is socket and the other is netlink.AF_ROUTE is used by socket, AF_NETLINK IS used by netlink socket.I suppose the two ways maybe have different.